# "glm\glm.hpp: No such file or directory" error on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, glm-math

***Running this command:***

```
g++ /workspace/2016FallCSE2022/Week15/glfw_examples/CarDriving2D/main.cpp -lGL -lglut -lGLEW -I/path/to/glm/headers
```

***Results in this error:***

```
In file included from /workspace/2016FallCSE2022/Week15/glfw_examples/CarDriving2D/GLSquare.h:9,
                 from /workspace/2016FallCSE2022/Week15/glfw_examples/CarDriving2D/CarDrivingGame.h:10,
                 from /workspace/2016FallCSE2022/Week15/glfw_examples/CarDriving2D/main.cpp:19:
/workspace/2016FallCSE2022/Week15/glfw_examples/CarDriving2D/Box2D.h:9:9: fatal error: glm\glm.hpp: No such file or directory
    9 | #include<glm\glm.hpp>
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

What is the error and how do I fix it?

Comment: (1) use `#include <glm/glm.hpp>`; see [Include Syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html). (2) install the GLM developer package, and not just the library. I believe the Ubuntu package is `libglm-dev`.